# How to set a UIButton tag with NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton

Is there another property like `tag` in `UIButton` where I can use to store `NSString`?

I know `tag` is an int so I can't store `@"myValue"`. I was wondering if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: You could subclass `UIButton` and add a property for this.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't anything similar to `tag` that takes an NSString.

Note that if you just want a descriptive tag, an enum can be useful.

```
enum ButtonTypes {
    ButtonTypeUnknown,
    ButtonTypeOK,
    ButtonTypeFoo,
    ButtonTypeBar,
    // etc...
};
```

Then later...

```
switch (mybutton.tag) {
    case ButtonTypeFoo:
        // handle this button type
        break;
    case ButtonTypeBar:
        // handle this button type
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up subclassing the UIButton and added the property I wanted. That was easy enough.